Django annotate over multi records forignkeys
I Work on a KPI system in which every manager can put specific questions for each user and answer them every month from 1 to 10
we have 4 departments, and every department says to have 4 question
these answers have to be calculated to return the % number for each department
Models

# question to answer every month

class Question(models.Model):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=USER_TYPE)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.question}"

# create every 01-month celery

class Kpi(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="kip_for")
    created_at = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "created_at")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} for Month {self.created_at.month}"

# group the answers by department

class DepartmentsKPI(models.Model):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=USER_TYPE)
    kpi = models.ForeignKey(
        Kpi, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="department_kpi"
    )

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="answer_for"
    )
    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    kpi_answers = models.ForeignKey(
        DepartmentsKPI,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="department_answers",
    )


the problem is when I apply the annotation over the KPI model to sum the answer score
for each department, the result becomes ungrouped so I have to group them by a unique value in my case the username
def get_kpi_range(*, year, month):
    queryset = (
        KPIRepository.filter_kpis(
            created_at__year=year,
            created_at__month=month,
        )
        .prefetch_related("department_kpi__department_answers")
        .annotate(
            score=Sum("department_kpi__department_answers__score")
            / Count("department_kpi__department_answers"),
            department=F("department_kpi__department"),
        )
        .values("id", "score", "department", username=F("user__username"))
    )

    grouped = [
        {"username": username, "kpis": list(instances)}
        for username, instances in itertools.groupby(queryset, lambda x: x["username"])
    ]

    return grouped

However, this fails to handle multiple records for the same user. If I query all KPIs in one year, the result becomes messy.
Also, if I want to make charts, I cannot return data for each user grouped by each month of the year
Current Result With grouped above
[
    {
        "username": "xxxxx",
        "kpis": [
            {
                "department": "HR",
                "score": 5
            },
            {
                "department": "IT",
                "score": 6
            },
            {
                "department": "QUALITY",
                "score": 4
            },
            {
                "department": "WFM",
                "score": 6
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "username": "ahmed",
        "kpis": [
            {
                "department": "IT",
                "score": 6
            }
        ]
    }
]

Without grouped
[
    [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "score": 5,
            "department": "HR",
            "username": "xxx"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "score": 6,
            "department": "IT",
            "username": "xxx"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "score": 4,
            "department": "QUALITY",
            "username": "xxx"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "score": 6,
            "department": "WFM",
            "username": "xxx"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "score": 6,
            "department": "IT",
            "username": "ahmed"
        }
    ]
]


group them how? Per username or per department?

the answers are already grouped by department, if I remove the grouped list above the result will be like that {username: "xx", department: "xx", score: 1 } If you don't understand me let me provide some screenshots

If I have 10 users that have 10 Kpi for the last 10 months and I want to Query all Kpi for the previous 10 Months the above query will return  {             "id": xx,             "score": xx,             "department": "xx",             "username": "xxx"         } x 4 department x 10 month if I add groupby the result will order by username not the date so maybe the HR KPI for Apr group with IT KPI for Mar

so what is the "wanted" result?

Same as the grouped above but allows the same user to have multi-record so if the user has 10 KPI should be like that [{username: "same-user", kpis: {total: 1, ...deps}}, {username: "same-user", kpis: {total: 1, ...deps}}, ]
